# Y-axis is repeating values - iOS Charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

In the [iOS Chart Framework](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) the y-values in the chart are repeating. As shown in the picture below there are multiple 0's and 1's in the chart.[image] Is there anyway I can customize this chart so there aren't any repeating y-values. So in this scenario ideally the y-values should be 1,2,3,4,5. I just don't want the y-values to repeat itself.

Comment: Looks like whatever is formatting the y-axis values is rounding to 0 decimal places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could also try:

```
/// When true, axis labels are controlled by the `granularity` property.
/// When false, axis values could possibly be repeated.
/// This could happen if two adjacent axis values are rounded to same value.
/// If using granularity this could be avoided by having fewer axis values visible.
public var granularityEnabled = false
```

and set `yAxis.granularity` = some value

Comment: Great! Thanks so much

Comment: Thank you, I added these 2 lines and it worked like a charm !  leftAxis.granularityEnabled = true
leftAxis.granularity = 1

Answer (score 2):

That's because the y-axis values currently have fractional values between 0 and 1. Those numbers are really 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, and 1. To format them properly try modifying the `valueFormatter` on the `ChartYAxis`:

```
let yAxis = chart.leftAxis

let yAxisValueFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
yAxisValueFormatter.usesSignificantDigits = true  // This will tell the formatter to display the decimal places
yAxis.valueFormatter = yAxisValueFormatter
```

The current range of the y-axis is 0 to 1 with 6 labels. If you add values greater than 1 then the range will automatically adjust. You can also use `customAxisMax` to force the max value if the current range is not suitable.